# Autoprefixer in npm script show TypeError: Patterns must be a string or an array of strings

Tags: css, npm, sass

When I run npm run prefix:css it show the

> **TypeError: Patterns must be a string or an array of strings**

```
{
  "name": "natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A natours project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css -w",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
    "concat:css": "concat -o css/style.concat.css css/icon-font.css 
                   css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' 
                   css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css"
   },
   "author": "Rahmat",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
      "concat": "^1.0.3",
      "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
      "postcss-cli": "^6.1.3"
    }
   }
```

This is my packge.json file

And the Error pic is -
[image]

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 3):

"prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b \"last 10 versions\" css/style.comp.css -o css/style.prefix.css",

i think you need to use string try with this...

Comment: must use the double quote and not single quote. This includes even trying to escape  the single quotes --> wont work.  this caught me for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last versions' 
               css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css"
```

Just remove the `10`, it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error check your `manifest.json` file.
if there was any empty array or empty code then just remove these code.

That's it.
I hope it will help you to fix this issue.

**My mistake was**

```json
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "use_dynamic_url": true,
      "resources": [""]
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by including relevant links to documentation